# Cannot download quagga from repository on internet

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I cannot find quagga with `apt-get install quagga`. Is there another way to get it? Or another package for setting up routing protocols?

Comment: What do you get when you run `apt-get install quagga`?  Paste the output it gives you to your question as an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The correct package name is `quagga`. It begins with <kbd>Q</kbd>, not <kbd>G</kbd>.

Try it:

```
apt-get install quagga
```

Comment: Sorry I misspelled it in my question, quagga doesn't get it either.

Comment: @StanleyClayton Please, include in your question the output of `apt policy`.